# form not submitting with submit button

Tags: php, html

I am making a contact from for my website, and it is not submitting when I click the submit button. http://tricksfortheweb.com/contact. Why isn't it submitting?

```
<div id="content">
      <h1>Contact Us</h1><hr>
      <form action="?contact=1" method="post">
        <p>Contact as...</p>
        <?php
                if(!$_SESSION["username"]){
                  echo "<!--";
                }
              ?><div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">

                <label><input type="radio" required name="contact_details" value="user" checked onclick="$('#enter-details').addClass('disabled')"> Current User (<a href="/account/?action=view"><?php echo $u; ?></a>)</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-9">

                <label><input type="radio" name="contact_details" value="new" onclick="$('#enter-details').removeClass('disabled')"> Enter details</label>

              <?php if(!$_SESSION["username"]){echo "-->";} ?>
                <div id="enter-details" class="<?php if(!$_SESSION['username']){ echo 'un'; } ?>disabled">
                  <input type="text" name="usern" class="form-control" placeholder="Name"><br>
                  <input type="email" name="emi" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
             <?php
                if(!$_SESSION["username"]){
                  echo "<!--";
                }
              ?>
          </div>
        </div><?php
                if(!$_SESSION["username"]){
                  echo "-->";
                }
              ?>
        <h3>Message:</h3> 
        <textarea class="form-control" name="contact_message" rows="10" required></textarea>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Contact" class="btn btn-primary">
      </form>
      <?php
        if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
          if($_POST["contact_details"] == "user"){
            $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$u'";
          }
        }
      ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have the following on the page:

```
$("form").submit(function(e, force){
    if(!force){

        e.preventDefault();
        if($("#username").val != "" && $("#password").val() != ""){
            $(this).trigger('submit', true);
        } else {
            $("#error").html("<span class='fa fa-circle-times'></span> All fields must be filled out.");
        }
    }
})
```

I think that you have that there for the login modal.

Is it possible that that `e.preventDefault();` is stopping all forms from submitting that aren't being triggered with the `force` flag?

Perhaps change the jQuery selector to be more specific, like `$("#modal-login-form").submit...` if the form has an ID of "modal-login-form"? This will stop the event from preventing the default submit action of all forms on the page.

Comment: Ah, thanks, in my code editor that doesn't show up, thanks.